# <meta ... redirect ... inside PHP tags

Tags: php, html, tags, meta

I have a question...
I've developed a php safe login page, now when I run a check to redirect the user with "`<?php header('location: home.php'); ?>`" It doesn't work while on the actual domain for whatever reason.

However I thought of this code

```
<?php 
if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {
echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=home.php'>";
}
?>
```

Would that code be safe and functional? I am most concerned with the privacy one could exploit. It seems to work while I am on my local server, I have not uploaded it yet.

Is there another way that would be better than what I have currently?

Comment: `header()` should work, have you looked into why it doesn't? Maybe post a question about that? :)

Comment: Well to answer your question it will be functional and the code you posted is safe. However I agree with @navnav you should look into why you didn't get `header` get to work.

Comment: To the now-deleted answer: `<?php header('LoCATion: http://www.google.com'); ?>` successful redirect. @luweiqi there you go ;-)

Comment: *"now when I run a check to redirect the user with "<?php header('location: home.php'); ?>" It doesn't work"* - That may be caused by an output before header.

Comment: I would add that it is actually *not* safe and functional as your application seems to send data to the visitor before the redirect, causing the header redirect to fail. You need to solve that as you don't want to send unknown data (error messages?) to unknown visitors.

Comment: @jeroen GMTA ;-) *buongiorno*

Comment: @Fred-ii- Buenos dias! Afternoon actually, but as you know it is always coffee time :-)

Comment: @jeroen *si signore, Señor* - sempre, sempre!

Comment: "now when I run a check" - maybe the condition (`login_check($mysqli) == true`) isn't evaluating to the expected value? I know that's super obvious, but just worth pointing out :)

Comment: Btw, does what you posted for code "work" here? You need to get into this conversation here, otherwise it's all guesswork.

Comment: Can you post the code surrounding your PHP header call? Is it in an `if` condition that isn't being met, or some other code block which is failing?

Comment: *"Would that code be safe and functional?"* - You haven't even told us if what you're using in what you posted, works or not. Edit: *"Is anybody home Sam?"* - @JayBlanchard

Comment: *I think they've left for parts unknown Ralph.* @Fred-ii-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would look into why `header()` isn't working on your remote server.

The call is triggered within a condition block, maybe the condition is failing (`login_check($mysqli) == true`). Have you checked that?

Another common cause for issues with `header()` is when the application outputs non-header data before calling `header()`. When you start to output data from a PHP script, PHP will automatically flush the headers. This means you cannot output any data before calling `header()`, as the header data will have already been flushed (so basically make sure you're not using `echo`, `print`, etc before your `header()` call.).

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Also, I've noticed that you're not killing the script after printing the meta refresh. I would kill the script after printing the meta refresh code to prevent any other content being served to the user. So perhaps:

```
if (login_check($mysqli) == true) {
  echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;URL=home.php'>";
  die;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answers, I got it to work. I figured that the <?php header... ?> had to be before <head> started. Now it seems to be working. I will try and make sure on multiple devices! Thank you very much!